# How much does it cost to become a theoretical physicists?

Tags: mathematical-physics

Does becoming a theoretical physicist require a huge amount of money? Does theoretical physics require the same resources as mathematics: just papers and pencil?

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is about a physicist career, and not physics.

Comment: [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Strange question! 
I assume that you are thinking about doing theoretical physics in your spare time. In this case, you a need a relative low amount of money. What you really need is a pc, an internet connection and some books. You can find books and articles online. It can be useful to attend seminars and schools in universities, so maybe you need some extra cash for this.

Answer (score 1):

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0080230768) contains some letters from Landau to young physicists:

> If you have enough will, you can study theoretical physics independently - after all, it requires nothing but books and paper.

(Mind you, Landau lived in Soviet Russia)

['t Hooft has similar advice](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~Gadda001/goodtheorist/index.html):

> It should be possible, these days, to collect all knowledge you need from the internet.

I think everyone in the US would agree you should go to a university, but that requires a huge amount of money, and with online connectivity that *may* be changing slightly. But that is not an easy question.

Comment: Yes obviously I will go for university and obtain a master , I just wonder after the master I have no chance on the particle collider and some new modern technology , which I don't know theoretical physics need these or not  , anyway , thanks for your advice ^^